# elem.innerHTML is only usable after a set timeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am currently working on an Angular1 app. I am getting data from an API and in the promise resolve (success) I first assign different values (some of them will be used in the view) and after that, I call a function to manipulate a specific text (add a border and background-color to a party of the sentence). I get the label with *document.getElementById* and afterwards use *label.innerHTML.replace(..)*.

However, the replace function does not do anything. And the view does not show a value for {{text}}. It only works if I use a timeout of 1 sec: the replace function works and the view text is updated (with a border and background-color).

Controller code with hacky setTimeout():

```
$scope.getTextAnalysis = function () {
    IntentRequestService.analyzeText($scope.intentApp.id, $scope.intentvalue)
      .success(function (response) {
        $scope.results = response;
        $scope.text = $scope.results.text;
        highlightEntities($scope.results);
      })
      .error(function (e) {
        ErrorHandlingService.logErrors(e);
      })
  };

  function highlightEntities(results) {
    var text = results.text;
    var entities = results.entities;
    _.forEach(entities, function (entity, i) {
      var entity_value = text.substring(entity.start, entity.end);
      var color = randomColor({
        luminosity: 'light'
      });
      var borderColor = ColorLuminance(color, -0.3);
      $scope.entities[i].backgroundColor = borderColor;
      $scope.entities[i].color = color;
      var label = document.getElementById('match-text');
      setTimeout(function(){ label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace(entity_value, '<span style="background-color:' + color + '; border: 3px solid ' + borderColor + ';" class="highlighted-entities">'+ entity_value + '</span>'); }, 1);
    });
  }
```

View:

```
<p class="md-subhead">Sentence:</p>
<h3 id="match-text"><span>{{text}}</span></h3>
```

Does anyone know how to do it without the timeout as I think it is a very hacky and ugly way to do it?

Comment: does 'match-text' gets data by ajax or some other dynamic way?
you might be overriding your changes...

Comment: it's the $scope.text variable I set in the promise resolving in $scope.TextAnalysis()

Answer (score 1):

Pass your label element to the function called by setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(label) {
  label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace(entity_value, '<span style="background-color:' + color + '; border: 3px solid ' + borderColor + ';" class="highlighted-entities">' + entity_value + '</span>');
}, 1, label);
```

Comment: The code above works as it is but I want an option without the setTimout . The replace() only works with setTimeout but I think this is not the best way to do it

Comment: Ummm ok looks like I didn't read properly. Looks like you have to wait for a better solution :(